# iOS development. Mysql? Sqlite? what's the best way?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I need to create an app linked with a remote database! Is mysql the best solution? Is Sqlite an only-local solution?

I use the following method and I would to know if it is the best way!

```
NSString *evento = @"1";
NSString *filtro = @"CAC2";

NSString *strURL = [NSString   
stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxx.com/Scripts/Evento/WIGriceviTipo.php?  
evento=%@&filtro=%@",evento, filtro];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
               [NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL   
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

strResult = [strResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet       
whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

mostra.text=strResult;

NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `Core Data`?  I do lots of remote database interaction and use CD for the local storage and just pass all the data to a web-service that digests it, checks for data integrity and then passes along the data to the database.

`Core Data` is a much easier learning curve than you might think and if you use a third party library like [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), it is even easier.

As far as the web server database goes, MySQL is the best option (IMO) if you are using a Linux based platform, SQL Server becomes an option if you are going the Windows Server route.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite shouldn't be used remotelly. From doc:

> If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a network, you should consider using a client/server database engine instead of SQLite.

In your code you could make this request asynchronous because you might be blocking your main thread while data is being retrieved. You may use `GCD` and enclose `dataWithContentsOfURL` with `dispatch_async` or use `NSURLConnection` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of SQLLite can be use remotely and it is better to have SQLLite database in mobile application development because it occupy low memory to store the data.

Please visit http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork